# What is the sum of $4\sqrt{28}$ and $3\sqrt{7}$ ?

Tags: irrational-numbers

As far as I can simplify it - 
$$4\sqrt{7*4} + 3\sqrt{7} 
= 8\sqrt{7} + 3 \sqrt{7} 
= \sqrt{7} * 11$$

However , The options for the correct answer are -
A) $ 8/3$
B)  $ 16/3$
C) $ 18/3$
D) $24/3$

I am a ninth grader so please try to explain in simple terms .

Comment: Probably some mixup, and they meant the _quotient_, not the sum. Your computation is correct.

Comment: What @DanielFischer said.

Comment: @Daniel Even if they meant the quotient , how could I reach one of the answers given in the options ?

Comment: Well, what is $$\frac{4\sqrt{28}}{3\sqrt{7}}?$$

Comment: Ninth grader deserves a little more: $$\sqrt{28}=\sqrt{4\cdot 7}=\sqrt 4\sqrt 7=2\sqrt 7\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a misprint , most probably they meant -  $$\dfrac{4\sqrt{28}} {3\sqrt{7}} 
= \dfrac{8\sqrt{7}}  {3\sqrt{7}} 
= \dfrac83 $$

In this case , the answer would be A) 8/3